# Visual Studio 2013 keyboard "Override Method" shortcut in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, unreal-engine4

So my question is simple, I found these [VS shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/) for VS 2013 and the Project.override (CTRL+ALT+INS) doesn't work for me, I even tried editing the 
edit.OverrideMembers one with no luck.

I want to know a simple way to obtain a list of overridable functions from a class and be able to implement them faster than just typing. Another person suggested that writing "override" (space) will give you a list, you choose the method from the list and just pressing (tab) will implement it, this doesn't work for me either.

Note: I'm working with C++ and this is happening on a header file using the Unreal Engine.

Comment: I don't really think it's possible for C++ in Visual Studio without some kind of extension. You've mentioned `override` - it's a keyword from C#, which works like a charm in that language, it lists any overridable method from base class, although it doesn't have any special meaning in C++. The closest partial solution I can think of is to write the name of base class with scope resolution operator (like in `A::`) - this will list all methods and fields of given class, but with no information, if they're virtual or not, so it isn't really useful, unless the class isn't too complex.

Comment: Yeah I could imagine, this is why I don't like C++ that much, after all the wonders on other languages (and IntelliJ), but well I'll have to get use to this, thanks for your help!. let's see if by any chance someone comes with a concrete solution.

Comment: @sukhoi191 Actually `override` is a keyword since C++11.

Comment: @Xaqq You're right, my mistake :) Although it's not a pure keyword as I see, but only an identifier that has no special meaning outside of class declaration. C++ compilers will not force you to use it, unlike aforementioned C# compilers, where override is necessary when one wants to, well, override a method.